# Why" list-style-image" attribute does not work

Tags: html, css, list

```
This is my css code:
ul{
list-style-type: square;
text-align:center;
list-style-position:inside;
color:blue;
line-height: 2rem;
list-style-image:url(icon.png);
}

and html code:
<body>
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>CSS Lists</h1>
    </header>
        <h1>Ordered List</h1>
    <ol start="5" reversed>
        <li>Step One</li>
        <li>Step Two</li>
        <li>Step Three</li>
    </ol>
       <h1>Unordered List</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Step One</li>
        <li>Step Two</li>
        <li>Step Three</li>
    </ul>
</article>
</body>
```

My icon image, html and css file are all saved in the same folder.

However, when i save my code, the icon does not appear on my web page.
Can anyone look into this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYEPX.png)`

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like this

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none; /* remove the default bullet markers */
  text-align:center;
  list-style-position:inside;
  color:blue;
  line-height: 2rem;
  list-style-image:url('icon.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be for different reasons.

first you forgot the ("")
but most likely the culprit is the link for the image try a relative path

so type

list-style-image = url("./icon.png")

the "." before the "/" will indicate that you are going from this directory.

Comment: Is there a way to change the size of the icon in the css code